# Setting default value in laravel migration issue

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

In my laravel application, I have two tables called users, and stat_user.

In my stat_user table I need to add a new column called, added_by.

added_by is a foreign key.

default value of added_by, has to be id of user's table.

How can I write my migrattion file to full fill both my needs to add that extra columns.

This is what I have done so far... I'm struggling to add that default value...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddAddedByToCertificateUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('stat_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('added_by')->after('user_id');
            $table->foreign('added_by')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('cstat_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('added_by');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, from where you can get the old added `stat_user` records users, 
i mean is this info stored anywhere in your DB? 
or do you want to attach all old records to a specific user?

Comment: yeah I'm trying to attach all old records @OmarTammam

Comment: Okay, will attach all to a  specific user ? or want to attach each record to a different user?

Comment: @VolkaDimitrev does your `stat_user` table have already data on it?

Comment: @aceraven777 stat_user is a very old table and it has data, earlier it doesn't had this added_by column, instead of that It had a column called, user_id to store the current logged in user's user id.  but now I need added_by column to be added. Since I already have some data in my table, I want this previously added user_id values to set as the default value of added_by column as well. Otherwise, for the old record that column will store 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, adding the new column with the relationship will cause an issue with the old records so we need first to make it `nullable`

```
  Schema::table('stat_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('added_by')->nullable()->after('user_id');
            $table->foreign('added_by')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

then we can run the following query to set the default value for the old records

```
\DB::statement('UPDATE stat_user SET added_by = user_id');
```

you can also combining them in the same migration file

```
public function up()
    {
        //
        Schema::table('stat_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('added_by')->nullable()->after('user_id');
                $table->foreign('added_by')->references('id')->on('users');
            });
        
        \DB::statement('UPDATE stat_user SET added_by = user_id');
                        
    }
```

Comment: Any chance if I could do the both jobs in single migration?

Comment: Yes you can put both this code in the `up` function of the migration